# How to create multiple files in numbered sequence based on user choice?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

So far I have this, where I create the number of folders I want within a chosen folder.  The number of folders created is based on my choice.

How do I make files within every one of those folders?  I want them to be numbered starting from 1, based on how many files I choose.

```
read -p "Enter the number of folders to create: " FOLDER_X
read -p "Enter the number of files to create: " FILE_Y

for (( x = 1; x <= FOLDER_X; x++ )); do 
mkdir $DIRY/$x

done

for i in {"$FILE_Y"}
do
echo hello > "$i.txt"
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob
DIR=/path/to/somewhere

while :; do
    read -p "Enter the number of folders to create: " folders
    read -p "Enter the number of files to create: " files
    [[ $folders,$files == +([[:digit:]]),+([[:digit:]]) ]] && break
    echo "Please provide numeric inputs."
done

for (( i = 0; i < folders; ++i )); do
    mkdir -p "$DIR/$i" || break

    for (( j = 0; j < files; ++j )); do
        echo hello > "$DIR/$i/$j.txt" || break 2
    done
done
```

Read the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Comment: Thank you.  The numeric only part is handy.  Looks like I was close, not too far off the mark.